# Profiling a multi-process program

Tags: c, linux, profiling, fork

I'd like to profile a program that forks and spawns several child processes. I want to see how much time is spent in some of the functions. What profiler can handle this job?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Oprofile](http://oprofile.sourceforge.net/news/) works well for this.

Comment: It seems like the right tool. I'm having some trouble using it without crashing the system, but that's a topic for a different question...

Answer (score 2):

I think you can do it with [SystemTap](http://sourceware.org/systemtap/) - [DTrace](http://www.sun.com/bigadmin/content/dtrace/) ideas implementation on Linux

Comment: It seems SystemTap is focused on profiling kernel functions and sysmtem calls, and isn't suitable for profiling user-space programs. DTrace seems nice, but isn't available on Linux AFAICS.

Answer (score 0):

Try [Zoom](http://rotateright.com) from RotateRight. It does system-wide profiling by default. If you have a later (2.6.32+) kernel, you can also get a timeline view of the scheduler behavior and system calls.